# Angular 6: Provider, deps not initialized

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular6

i've got a problem while using a custom Provider in angular 6 in combination with [ngx-envconfig](https://github.com/kmanaseryan/ngx-envconfig).

My custom provider looks like this:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: LoggerConfig, useFactory: LoggerConfigFactory, deps: [ConfigService] },
  ],
```

with this implementation:

```
export const LoggerConfigFactory = (configService: ConfigService) => {
  const logUrl = configService.getApi('Log');   
  const loggerConfig = new LoggerConfig();
  return loggerConfig;
};
```

an error occurs during the first line:

```
      const logUrl = configService.getApi('Log');
```

because the Config Service [1](https://github.com/kmanaseryan/ngx-envconfig) is not yet initialized (the injection is made, but i can't call any methods, because the data is not loaded at this point in time).

How can i ensure, that the injected dependency is initialized when injected into my custom provider?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add `ConfigService` to the *providers* list.

```
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    { provide: LoggerConfig, useFactory: LoggerConfigFactory, deps: [ConfigService] },
  ],
```

Try adding `ConfigService` to *providers* list.

Comment: Unfortunately doesnt' work, ConfigService is available, but not initialized.